# Raise event when string changed

Tags: wpf, port

I need to create some interface to read data from iButton. Actually it work's like that: user applies little pendant with magnet to iButton device -> log in him. User take away pendant - logout.

My problem is that, I know how to relog, by simple:

```
 public static void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sp.ReadLine() == "logout")
            {
               logoutUser();
            }
            else 
            {
                //put data into nonstatic textbox from another window
               // or raise some event which will listen to changes in data and put string into textbox
            }
        }
```

But how can I raise event when data != "logout" (for example A0019293881, as pin code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own event, an lauch then in the `else` clause, then  create some method to hear the event an do what you want.

More about events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)